# Font looks distorted in windows

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-face

Iam doing a website in ubuntu and finished with UI part. Everything was working smoothly in ubuntu but when i switched on to windows all the fonts are distorted. I tried the following code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'garrisonsb';
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-bold.svg#garrison_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'garrisons';
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-regular.svg#garrison_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'rupee';
    src: url('../fonts/Rupee.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Rupee.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Rupee.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Rupee.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Rupee.svg#rupeeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

the specified code is been generated using squirrel-generator. I tried with font-smooth property set to 'always' and also with -webkit-font-smoothing set to antialiased and the font-weight was also specified as 700 for regular and 900 for bold instead of 'normal', but nothing worked.

please suggest optimum solution......

Comment: Are you talking about Google Chrome?

Comment: problem is with all browsers..

Comment: Since this is a visual issue with the font, you should include a picture of the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Font rendering is different in different environments, and for the most of it, you cannot control it (especially as regards to Windows users). As you don’t even disclose identification of the fonts, or screenshots of the problem, or online demos, this looks like a non-question.

Comment: Since the website is in beta phase i cannot disclose the contents... I can only say the font is garrisons as explained in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Web fonts are not smooth in all the browsers. You may have to use `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` for web-kit browsers.

You better use `text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #GOOD-COLOR-HERE` or `text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(COLOR-SETTINGS-HERE)` and tweak the color settings and shadow for the best result.

Answer (score 0):

When saying the problem stays within all the browsers it pops the question, is something wrong with your font or maybe something else? 
Can you try to do that with another custom font in Windows to see the result?

Though the solution @Madhu Rox provided is pretty cutting edge.

Comment: Not an answer. Should have been posted as a comment.